# Fetch data when internet connection comes back in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, connectivity

I'm developing an app that fetchs some data from the internet. In order to avoid issues with the internet connection I added the [connectivity package](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity).

If internet is connected when the app starts and then the internet connection is switched off, I can display a Container with the Text of "no internet". If I switch internet on again, the data is displayed.

The code to achive this is the following:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';

class CheckNetworkPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CheckNetworkPageState createState() => _CheckNetworkPageState();
}

class _CheckNetworkPageState extends State<CheckNetworkPage> {
  StreamSubscription<ConnectivityResult> _networkSubscription;

  Future<List<Data>> fetchData() async {

  // Code to fetch data

 }


  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchData();
    _networkSubscription = Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen((ConnectivityResult result) {
     _connectionStatus = result.toString();
     print(_connectionStatus);

     if (result == ConnectivityResult.wifi ||
      result == ConnectivityResult.mobile ||
      result == ConnectivityResult.none) {
      print("Result: $result");
      setState(() {});
  }
    });
  }

// Cancel subscription after you are done
  @override
  dispose() {
    super.dispose();

    _networkSubscription.cancel();
  }

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // More code. I can use the result of _connectionStatus to build my app
   }
 }
```

However, if the app starts without internet, when I switch it on, the data doesn't load, as it is fetched in `initState()`.

**How to fetch the data when it was no fetched before and internet connection is switched on**?

Comment: At first glance there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your code. Are the connectivity changes not triggering at all?

Comment: The code above works as expected. However, if I start the app for the first time without internet and then I switch internet on while the app is running, the data is not displayed. The data is displayed if I start the app with internet connection. I want to load the data when I switch internet on but data has not been downloader yet.

Comment: I understand, but my question stands, when you turn the internet on after starting the app with it off, is the connectivity listener picking up the change and triggering your code?

Comment: In that case if I start the app I get `ConnectivityResult.none`, and when I switch internet on I get `ConnectivityResult.wifi` as expected

Comment: Then you should be able to just fetchData() when the ConnectivityResult is wifi or mobile. The answer that you marked as correct below will cause an error when you don't have Connectivity. It will still try to fetch the data.

Answer (score 1):

You could store latest fetched data in a variable.

```dart
List<Data> fetchedData;

Future<List<Data>> fetchData() async {

  // Code to fetch data
  // Add this :
  fetchedData = ...
}
```

Then in your listener, check whether this data is defined :

```dart
if (result == ConnectivityResult.wifi ||
    result == ConnectivityResult.mobile ||
    result == ConnectivityResult.none) {
        print("Result: $result");
        setState(() {});
        // Add this : 
        if (fetchedData == null) fetchData()
}
```

Comment: but where do you put the listener, which will be called on every application screen?